# NextJS - JSON File produce Column Layout Shift?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, pagespeed, cls

Hey guys Im on the hunt for page speed ;), and literally just the CLS (Columns Layout Shift) breaks my neck...
I have a JSON file which holds all the content for my page and it gets loaded dynamically to my Components like: (easy example, in production the json is much bigger...)

```
import data from "./Model.json";

export default function Component (){
return <div>{data.text}</div>
}
```

Do you think in the first time my div is height 0 and after the content comes from the model.json the div is growing and thats the reason I got these CLS ?

Greeting and Thanks for any helps :heart:

Comment: You need to use `getStaticProps()` function. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your reply! Now it looks like: import data from „./model.json“ and in my getStaticProps(){return {props: data}} still habe this cls issue :/

Comment: Did you pass `props` in your component?

Comment: Yeah I did! Maybe I have to show my full code ;)

Comment: Yes it's better if you show your code. It will be easier to help you. If possible on https://codesandbox.io/